# GRE supported in kernel but iproute2 cant create GRE tunnel

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, embedded, tunneling

Im trying to create IP over GRE tunnel but i get No such device:

```
ip tunnel add gre0 mode gre remote 192.168.152.22 local 192.168.152.21 ttl 255
ioctl: No such device
```

I have compiled GRE support in my kernel:

```
CONFIG_NET_IPGRE_DEMUX=y
CONFIG_NET_IPGRE=y
CONFIG_NET_IPGRE_BROADCAST=y
```

There is not `gre0` interface when interfaces are displayed via `ifconfig -a` where i see all available network interfaces (also those not upped yet).

My kernel version is 2.6.30.9 and `iproute2` version is 2-2.6.33.

`ip tunnel show` displays:

```
ip tunnel show
ioctl: Invalid argument
tunl0: ip/ip  remote any  local any  ttl inherit  nopmtudisc
sit0: ipv6/ip  remote any  local any  ttl 64  nopmtudisc 6rd-prefix 2002::/16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was GRE demultiplexer module required by ip_gre. When kernel loads GRE demultiplexer driver registers protocol 47 handle so when ip_gre.c attempted to do the same it fails because it has been registered before. It is solved by modifying ip_gre.c to not register protocol GRE handle.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're looking for is:

```
ip tunnel add <name> mode <mode> ...
```

E.g.:

```
ip tunnel add gre0 mode gre ...
```

The name is an arbitrary text string, it can be anything you want. I usually name the tunnels after the remote side for clarity.

Comment: I am sorry i wrote command with bad syntax, im going to edit the question, but im testing now with `ip tunnel add gre0 mode gre..` and the result is the same, `ioctl: no such device`.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute:

```
modprobe ip_gre
```

Before your command.